# Reset previous values in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to write a BOF service which on certain condition it updates me some values,for example i can input the sales Id and it updates me that sales id field on other tables and then I can undo the operation.Can you please give me some hints.

Comment: Please be aware that the stack overflow format is not suited for such broad question (see also [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Try asking more specific questions and show us some code of your implementation to increase your chances to receive an answer.

Comment: See http://www.agermark.com/2011/11/call-bof-service-with-caller-record.html